# Is it possible to create an attribute that encapsulates a group of fields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, access-modifiers

In unity you can expose fields to the editor by making them public or with the attribute [SerializeField]. Obviously SerializeField is safer in terms of accessibility, but it looks quite messy when you have a bunch of fields that need to be exposed. See here:

```cs
//editor exposed fields
[SerializeField]
string _name;
[SerializeField]
BlockType _blockType;
[SerializeField]
Sprite _sprite;
[SerializeField]
float _happinessMod, _pollutionMod;
```

but what I would like to do is create two attributes that encapsulate a group of fields, like this:

```cs
//editor exposed fields
[SerializeFieldBlock]
string _name;   
BlockType _blockType;    
Sprite _sprite;  
float _happinessMod, _pollutionMod;  
[SerializeBlockEnd]
```

As you can see the code in the second example is far more readable than the first. Is this possible? I've never coded an attribute before.

Comment: Please don´t add code as image. Add it as formatted text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of built-in classes that you can use to group attributes visually in the inspector, such as [SpaceAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpaceAttribute.html) and [HeaderAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html). See an example usage of them:

```cs
public class AttributesTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Attributes 1 to 4")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float attribute1;

    [SerializeField]
    private string attribute2;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject attribute3;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> attribute4;

    [Space(25)]
    [Header("Attributes 5 to 8")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float attribute5;

    [SerializeField]
    private string attribute6;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject attribute7;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> attribute8;
}
```

This results in the following:

[image: Example usage of Space and Header]

If you have further specific needs, you can create your own decorator drawers by extending `DecoratorDrawer`. The [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DecoratorDrawer.html) offers a good explanation about how you could use it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution might be to encapsulate all of your fields into a separate data class. All of these properties should be publicly accessible, as long as you have a reference to the object.
This class can be instantiated and assigned to a field in your original class. In order to expose all of its properties to the editor, mark the whole object field as `[SerializedField]`.

```
[Serializable]
public class EncapsulatedProperties
{
    public string _name;
    public BlockType _blockType;
    public Sprite _sprite;
    public float _happinessMod, _pollutionMod;
}

public class OriginalClass
{
    [SerializeField]
    private EncapsulatedProperties props;
}
```

Only do so, however, if this way of Encapsulation makes sense within the scope of your unity project.